# Linq or multiple database calls?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm using C#/Asp.Net/Entity Framework to retrieve my data which when combined with linq makes it super easy for even novices like me to retrieve data.

I have a particular scenario that I'm looking for advice on.

I have a relatively small data table (200 products), however being EF, there are other tables retrieved at the same time.

I use data from this table up to 10 times in succession like this:

```
type = 1;
subtype = 1; // do something with this

type = 1;
subtype = 2; // then do something with this
```

You get the picture - it's always the same type, but then I do other things based on subtype - I currently extract these subtypes using linq - so I make 1 db call on type then process the rest using linq.

The question is, would it be better just to make 10 calls to the db using type and subtype each time? It would certainly make for tidier code but I'm guessing it likely to be less performant.

Comment: What's your definition of "better"?

Comment: Why don't you select all product records and join(`Include`) them with the `Type` and `Subtype`(i guess it's the same `Type`-table, isn't it?). Then you have all informations you need in one query. Show your query.

Comment: Well to be honest, as long as amount of your data is not huge its ok, when its gets huge and sql-server cant handle it there u should be worrying. read about stored procedure and how to create them with entity framework, also what @TimSchmelter said you should dig that as well (assuming you haven't done it already?! which is odd)

Comment: Better covers all things - I don't consider myself experienced enough to know all the pros and cons but I can make an informed decision if there are arguments for either.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Tim, I can do that (its what I currently do - I select on type from the database, then use linq to do things with subtypes. I guess the argument is, with the tables being so small would it be a better design just to make 10 calls to the db instead of 1?

Comment: You have a working solution that has enough performance = not broken = don't fix it. That amount of entries considered, both possibilities should be equally valid. If entries were *much* more, you could probably take advantage of your DBMS's indexes. This could outperform fetching all and filter through linq. But I'm talking about probably millions of entries, then.

Comment: I don't think it is worth it, but you could just try it out: Implement both and set up a decent performance benchmark. But personally, I'd not invest the effort *in this case*. At least not until performance becomes an issue.

Comment: @Fildor - thanks for your advice

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation to me...

Comment: @Patrick - prematurely optimising implies that I know what I'm doing - quite the opposite - because linq and EF make data retrieval so easy, it's easy to use the wrong tool for the job without realising.

Comment: It's only the wrong tool once it starts to cause a problem :). Having said that I'm not a fan of EF - perhaps look at dapper, the ORM providing the data on this very page

Comment: If what you are doing is working and performing OK with a realistic volume and type of data leave it. The three rule of optimization, don't do it, don't do it yet, profile. When it's actually a problem profile and find out where to optimize. There are some good tools like Glimpse or Entity Framework Profile or db profilers when you actually need to look at it.